# Ics features on the previous android versions

Tags: android

I'm working on a project should have an ICS-ish design with the UI elements presented on these mockups:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The thing is that minSDK requirement is API 7. What would be the best way to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize to get all of those UI elements and it's probably the best way to do it in this case.

Check out ActionBarSherlock, it's gonna help you with design 1-4.

For the last two you simply customize the theme to show the images that you wanted.
The Spinner design is going to be tricky I reckon since the selection in pre-honeycomb presents as a dialog and used up full screen. It's possible, but I just don't know the best way to do it yet.